# Angular 2 and systemjs: How to import into app.module.ts file that will be created in runtime?

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

Think about a project with reusable angular 2 components. Now on runtime I copy the components files into another project so I want to be able to use them. How it should be done?

The first problem is the file path not recognized by .ts, it doesn't really exists, will be exists on run-time.

```
import { HelloComponent } from 'my-framework/components/hello/hello.component.ts';
```

this import seems to work, altouge .ts don't recognize the URL, but in loading he find the file. Now I'm getting error on that file itself, which I don't understnad way. How the file is being compile to the project?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'hello',
    template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`
})
export class HelloComponent { name = 'You'; }
```

Did someone created a project with components and insert them to another project and being able to use them? I think I don't understand how it is being done.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.module.ts file make sure you're declaring the component:

`````

```
import { HelloComponent } from 'my-framework/components/hello/hello.component';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        HelloComponent
    ]
```

`````